# JSONSTORE init fails for mobilefirst (version 7.1) ionic cordova applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have integrated my existing ionic project with mobilefirst cordova. When I try to initialize JSONSTORE it fails with error operation_failed_on_specific_document

Comment: Please edit your question with the MobileFirst version used and the code you have implemented.

Comment: Do you have some code you can share with us? Are you using the JSONStore getting started?

Comment: How did you build the Cordova app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing this problem on android, be sure that the jsonstore.jar is correct configured in your project.

It must be listed in file "[YOURPROJECT]/.idea/libraries/libs.xml" like this:

```
<root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/libs/jsonstore.jar!/" />
```

[The project tree before and after the fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmLh1.png)

Regards,

Bernardo Baumblatt.

Comment: Thanks, It was missing and I have added this to libs.xml, now I am getting PERSISTENT_STORAGE_FAILURE error